# Is global variables are shared between instances? Ruby on rails + Unicorn + Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, global-variables, unicorn

We have a one RoR application where we used one global variable.

When we tried to `HTTP` requests from multiple browsers, for fraction of seconds it's getting `nil`, again after few seconds refresh it get filled with value.

Not sure what's the happening here, is Global variable shared between multiple `HTTP` requests, and due to latency creating over there?

It will more helpful if I get more detailed information on Global variables.

Comment: Which global variable you are using ? is it ruby global variable `$` or `ENV` variable or `Thread` variable ?

Comment: Also, how are you serving your RoR app? In particular, do you have a pool, like Passenger's `PassengerMaxPoolSize`? It is conceivable that one of your processes' global is being set, while another's is not...

Comment: @AnilMaurya -ruby global variable

Answer (score 3):

> again after few seconds refresh it get filled with value.

It probably has nothing to do with the fact that your waiting a few seconds. If anything when you refreshed the browser, nginx forwarded your request to a *different* Ruby process than the request before.

*Global variables are only global within the same process* - If you are running 2 Ruby processes, and set a global variable in the first the second won't see this.

If you really want to share data between multiple processes, using a database is the standard way.

Comment: actually I don't want share data between process. Main problem that I am facing is that my ruby global variable getting `nil` suddenly. Any hint on how to trace it?

Comment: It's because by default unicorn is launching multiple processes for you. You cannot use a global variable because you don't know which process your request will hit.

Comment: Read here if you want to adjust your number of unicorn workers. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-optimize-unicorn-workers-in-a-ruby-on-rails-app if you set it to 1 your code should work at the cost of reduced performance because you only have one process.